# removing xgboost.model leftover file

Tags: r, xgboost

Every time I use xgboost in R (and maybe python too) I discover an `xgboost.model` file in the directory I was working in.  Deleting this file does not create any problems for my next run of xgboost.  I don't like this file, and wish it would never show up.  Is there a setting I can change to make xgboost stop creating this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also add `save_period = NULL` as an argument to the `xgboost` / `xgb.train` call to stop it from saving any file.

Answer (score 1):

`xgb.train` has `save_name` parameter - the name or path of the file (default: "xgboost.model"), you can change it and save the file where it won't bother you.